# MS Access 2007 SQL Query: Nested (COUNT, GROUP BY) in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a tracking log which I'm using to determine the urgency of Proposals AND Underwriter availability. So far I've made two separate queries: one that displays proposals ORDER BY whether they're expedited and when they're due, and the other that displays COUNT OF proposals for each underwriter.

My goal is to add a select statement to the ProposalUrgency query that shows the count of proposalIDs that are assigned to the Underwriter in each row. This provides a vertical view of when proposals are due, plus a horizontal view of whether the assigned underwriter has the bandwidth to complete it by the due date.

So far my research isn't turning up any answers to this type of question, although it could be that I'm not understanding an answer as it pertains to this situation.

```
CREATE TABLE Proposals (
  ProposalID int PRIMARY KEY,
  ReceivedDate date(),
  Client varchar(255),
  Underwriter varchar(255),
  Expedite boolean(),
  DueDate date(),
  Completed date(),
)
```

'ProposalUrgency' query:

```
SELECT Expedite
  , DueDate
  , Underwriter
  , ReceivedDate
  , Client
FROM Proposals
WHERE Completed IS NULL
ORDER BY Expedite, DueDate, RecievedDate;
```

'UnderwriterWorkload' query:

```
SELECT Underwriter
  , Count('proposalID') AS OpenGroups
FROM Proposals
WHERE Completed IS NULL
GROUP BY Underwriter
ORDER BY Count('GroupName');
```

Comment: will be helpful if show the desired result or better yet use `sqlfiddle.com` or `rextester.com`

Comment: So you are looking to add the 'openGroups' total in the underwriterWorkload query to the main ProposalUrgency query?

Comment: Hm... I though `SELECT COUNT('a')` would just return 1, since it counts a constant, but apparently that crashes MS Access 2016. Still, don't count constants.

Comment: IIUC - just join the two queries by *Underwriter* field in a third query.

Comment: @Twelfth, yes, that's correct.

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99026c/2)

Comment: i would normally say turn the second query into a sub query and join it to proposals on underwriter = underwriter...but I just realized this is in access and I'm not certain how to do sub-queries in access or if it can be done at all.

Comment: @Parfait, can possibly do that, but do you know whether joining two queries is best practice? Not sure whether I should keep pursuing a single query to rule 'em all.

Comment: Fiddle is in MySQL...access or MySQL?

Comment: I'm trying to build in Access, not MySQL. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Access is an odd psuedo-SQL language (kinda the tiny brother to MSSQL) and uses a lot of unique syntax that you won't see in other SQL flavours.  I think you may have to create the underwriterWorkload query as a view and then join the table to the view on the underwriter field...but you probably want to get someone more versed with MS Access to say for sure.  This may help though https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76816/alternative-to-sub-query-in-ms-access

Comment: @VesperAnnstas ... joining two queries is more efficient than nested subqueries.

Comment: Ok, I'll work on joining the two queries using the link Twelfth provided. Thank you Twelfth and Parfait!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Subquery does work in Access (at least Access 2013), I know it's a "single query to rule them all" approach, but it does work...

```
    SELECT P.Expedite, P.DueDate, P.Underwriter, P.ReceivedDate, P.Client, 
        (SELECT Count(1) 
         FROM Proposals Kt 
         WHERE P.Underwriter = Kt.Underwriter AND Kt.Completed IS NULL 
         GROUP BY Kt.Underwriter) As Kt
    FROM Proposals P
    WHERE P.Completed IS NULL
    ORDER BY Expedite, DueDate, ReceivedDate
```